# How do I create a subset of an array based on an array of indexes for that array in Ruby

Tags: ruby, arrays, indexing, subset

If I have an array like this:

```
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20]
```

and I want to select a subset of that array based on this arbitrary array of indexes:

```
[0,1,4,7,8,13,14,15,18,19]
```

with the result being this subset of the first array:

```
[1,2,5,8,9,14,15,16,19,20]
```

My question is, how do I make a simple function (1 or 2 lines) out of the array of indexes and the starting array to get the subset?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20]
indexes = [0,1,4,7,8,13,14,15,18,19]

arr.values_at(*indexes) # => [1, 2, 5, 8, 9, 14, 15, 16, 19, 20]
```

Comment: Nice, I knew there was something simple

Answer (score 0):

```
arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20]
index = [0,1,4,7,8,13,14,15,18,19]
arr.select.with_index{|m,i| m if index.include? i}
#=> [1, 2, 5, 8, 9, 14, 15, 16, 19, 20]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20]
index = [0,1,4,7,8,13,14,15,18,19]

arr.each_with_index {|value,index| p value if indexes.include?(index)}
```